# Stale data when reading from the serial port

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, serial-port

Our C# application communicates with devices over the serial port. The protocol is a simple request/response like protocol.

Everything works fine most of the time, but on some machines we sometimes experience timeouts and stale data for the responses of the following requests.

I wrote a single-threaded console application and managed to reproduce the problem reliably in a virtual machine where I limited the CPU to about 10%. The application basically does the following:

```
_port = new SerialPort(
    "COM1",
    115200,
    Parity.None,
    8,
    StopBits.One)
{
    RtsEnable = false,
    DtrEnable = false,
    Handshake = Handshake.None,
    ReadTimeout = 5000
    WriteTimeout = 5000
};

_port.Open();
_port.DiscardInBuffer();
_port.DiscardOutBuffer();


_readBuffer = new byte[1024];

// Send requests periodically...
while (true)
{
    var requestBytes = ...;                 // Encode the request
    _port.Write(requestBytes, 0, requestBytes.Length);

    try
    {
        var responseStream = new List<byte>(1024);
        int count = ...;                        // Calculate number of bytes of the response
        int remainingBytesCount = count;
        while (numberOfBytesReadTotal < count)
        {
            int bytesToRead = Math.Min(_readBuffer.Length, remainingBytesCount);
            int numberOfBytesRead = _port.Read(_readBuffer, 0, bytesToRead);
            if (numberOfBytesRead <= 0)
                break;

            remainingBytesCount -= numberOfBytesRead;

            responseStream.AddRange(_readBuffer.Take(numberOfBytesRead));
        }

        // Parse the response and if it is valid, dump it. Otherwise throw an exception
        var response = ParseResponse(responseStream);
        Console.WriteLine(FormatResponse(response));
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ERROR OCCURED: " + err);
        Console.WriteLine("Sleep some time, then discard in and out buffers and then proceed");
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        _port.DiscardInBuffer();
        _port.DiscardOutBuffer();
    }
}
```

For a short period of time it works successfully, but then suddenly while in the middle of reading a response, the Read()-call inside the read-loop times out and throws a `TimeoutException`.

As you can see the application waits for 10 seconds to ensure that the device has sent the remaining data. Then we discard the in and out buffers of the serial port and start over.

Now there is the really strange effect that I don't understand: for the next request, the data that's read is stale data that hasn't been read from the previous request that timed out! In my opinion that shouldn't happen because I discarded the in and out buffers.

To make sure that the problem is not the device itself, one of our engineers put a digital oscilloscope in front of the device and logged data traffic: the device quickly responds to the request and sends all response data within a second to the computer so there should be no timeout. And second, it doesn't send the wrong data as a response to the request that follows the request that timed out.

The problem seems to have something to do with the speed of the CPU. When I run the virtual machine with full speed, the test application runs successfully for minutes until I stop it. The more I lower the CPU speed, the sooner the bug appears.

The device behaves correctly and the small console application seems to be correct. It looks like there is a problem on the serial port driver.

Does anybody have some tips what I could try?

### Edit

- I have found one bug: the baud rate must be 115200 baud and not 115000. That didn't help, though.
- As suggested in the comments, I have read the blog post and tried to read directly from the BaseStream, but this didn't work.
- Then I completely threw away C#'s SerialPort and use WinAPI, and this didn't work either.
- What's really strange: when the timeout occurs and I close and restart the test application, the stale data of the previous request of the previous run is received! This should not be possible in my opinion. I have also done a ClearCommError to see if there is something in the serial port driver's read queue and it is empty. To be safe, I did a PurgeComm after opening the port and before sending the request, but the problem was still there.

Comment: Unfortunatel, I don't have a serial port to try anything.
What about the event DataReceived? Instead of wait (and block the application) for a synchronous read, you could try to create an event handler and attach it to DataReceived.
This would deal with problems related to processes sharing CPU time and getting stalled.

Comment: is it a true com port or a usb to com port? You could perform a read within the catch (in a loop in case of failure) to assist n the flushing, or close and reopen the connection.

Comment: `In my opinion that shouldn't happen because I discarded the in and out buffers.` Is that what the docs say should happen?

Comment: I've found this by googling, telling how to achieve good behaviour from SerialPort:
http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Comment: The code looks fine; but having read @Baltasarq link, I am deeply suspicious that any code, no matter how well written, that uses serial port classes is going to be reliable.

Comment: It is a true com port. Interesting article - I adjusted the test application to use the BaseStream and ReadAsync, but it didn't help. The next thing I'll try is to program against WinAPI directly.

Comment: Data getting "stuck" and suddenly releasing when the port is re-initialized tends to be a handshaking problem.  We don't know much about what the device requires, all we can see is the least-likely-to-be-correct code.  Very few devices deal well with Handshake.None and the handshake lines forced off.  Don't do that.

Comment: @HansPassant So it's an issue per se of the device / protocol? Is there anything I can do in software to work around this?

Comment: @HansPassant The weird thing is: the device is actually sending the whole response data to the computer, but it isn't received in my application. I also tried to increase the input buffer to a 16K and receive timeout to 30 seconds, but that didn't help either. It feels a bit like it is put into the serial port receive buffer, but not made available to my application.  When I restart it, the receive buffer is still empty. Then I send the first request and as a response I get back what the device has sent in the run before. Thus, it must be cached somehwere :-(